# htaccess rewrite not working?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I tried a long time but don't understand this.
I have the following code in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$  $1\.php

RewriteRule ^product/([0-9])/$ product?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^product - [L]
```

The last 2 RewriteRule's won't work. 
sample url: `www.samplesite.com/product?id=444100`
I want rewrite it to: `ww.samplesite.com/product/444100`

Could you please help me ?

Thanks inadvance !

Answer (score 0):

`[0-9]` will match only a single digit.

Have it like this in different order:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^product/(\d+)/?$ product?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$  $1.php [L]
```